# XMLHttprequest only save 4 data sometimes 3 or 1 data

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

Would like to ask why my xmlhttrequest only save one to 4 data not the whole list.
I put my XMLHttprequest inside the looping since this is the list of data.
Here is my Code:

```
 var currentdate = new Date();
    for (var x = 1; x <= t ; x++)
    {

        if ($.trim($('#TherDesc' + x).val()) != '' && $.trim($('#deg' + x).val()) != '' &&
            $.trim($('#lims' + x).val()) != '' && $.trim($('#Therremarks' + x).val()) != '' &&
            $('#Therimg' + x).val() != null)
        {
            var h;
            var fileInputs = document.getElementById('Therimg' + x);
            h = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-" + currentdate.getDay() + "-" + currentdate.getHours() + "-" + currentdate.getMinutes() + "-" + $('#Therpoint' + x).val() + "-" + id + "-" + fileInputs.files[0].name;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', serverpath + '/Home/save_ther_points');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('IMAGE_NAME', h);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('ANALYSIS_ID', id);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('POINT_NUM', $('#Therpoint' + x).val());
            xhr.setRequestHeader('DESCRIPTION', $('#TherDesc' + x).val());
            xhr.setRequestHeader('DEGR', $('#deg' + x).val());
            xhr.setRequestHeader('LIMIT', $('#lims' + x).val());
            xhr.setRequestHeader('REMARKS', $('#Therremarks' + x).val());
            xhr.send(fileInputs.files[0]);
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e)
            {

            }
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4)
                {

                }
            }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It’s likely fires asynchronous request for which loop doesn’t wait. Try using recursive function with timeout checking when you get result and then firing new request. JQuery has alternative to xhr.

Comment: Thanks bestinamir. Would like to ask if it's possible to apply the recursive function with timeout checking in loop? Sorry but im still a beginner on using xmlhttprequest :)

Comment: I am also. You don’t need a loop because recursion is a (infinite) loop where you wait and iterate and specify exit condition you want to achieve https://link.medium.com/98MI4MDv96